# How can I fix the colored title bar of Office 2010 applications on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office-2010

With the last major Windows 10 update (version 1511), colored title bars were introduced. I think they look rather spiffy, but Office 2010 doesn't play well with it. It's not completely unusable, but it is distressingly ugly.

[image]

Is there any way I can make it solid blue, or turn off the colors for Office 2010 applications without turning it off altogether?